# how to mock Supabase with Flutter for unit testing?

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, mocking, supabase

I'm trying to do unit test with Supabase in Flutter like the code bellow:

```
import 'package:bloc_test/bloc_test.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';


class TestMClass {
  SupabaseClient client;
  TestMClass({
    required this.client,
  });
  Future<AuthResponse> signinMc() async {
    final respnse = await client.auth
        .signInWithPassword(email: 'example@gmail', password: 'password');
    return respnse;
  }
}

class MockSupabaseClient extends Mock implements SupabaseClient {}

void main() async {
  
  final MockSupabaseClient mockClient = MockSupabaseClient();

  final TestMClass testMCass = TestMClass(client: mockClient);
  setUp(() {});
  group('TestAuthBloc', () {
    test('description', () async {
      final auth = await testMCass.signinMc();
      expect(auth, isA<AuthResponse>());
    });
  });
}
```

it throw this error:....

> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'GoTrueClient'

how I can Mock or do unit testing for Supabase functions with Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fake class like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:supabase/supabase.dart';

void main() {
  test('Fake Supabase', () async {
    final supabase = FakeSupabase();

    final response = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword(
      email: 'test@gmail.com',
      password: 'passsword',
    );
    expect(response.session, isA<Session>());
  });
}

class FakeSupabase extends Fake implements SupabaseClient {
  @override
  get auth => FakeGotrue();
}

class FakeGotrue extends Fake implements GoTrueClient {
  final _user = User(
    id: 'id',
    appMetadata: {},
    userMetadata: {},
    aud: 'aud',
    createdAt: DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
  );
  @override
  Future<AuthResponse> signInWithPassword(
      {String? email,
      String? phone,
      required String password,
      String? captchaToken}) async {
    return AuthResponse(
      session: Session(
        accessToken: '',
        tokenType: '',
        user: _user,
      ),
      user: _user,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How can you be sure that this will return exactly the same as Supabase would?

Comment: @khagen You don't. That is not what mocking is. If you want to test against an actual Supabase instance, you can use the Supabase CLI to start a local Supabase instance. You can configure it to run in Github Actions too to automate your tests.

Answer (score 0):

To Add to what was said above for mocking responses such as `Stream<AuthState>` which is the return type from the onAuthStateChange function, and you, for example wanted to test how your logic responds to different auth responses you can implement static methods that return the different states you want your code to handle:

```dart
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
// ^^ For Testing Value Equality, since flutter doesn't have that out of the box
// which is something you'll probably want for unit testing

class SupabaseAuthFixture extends Equatable {
  static Stream<AuthState> unauthenticated() async* {
// ^^ static means we can call it without an instance of the class
// ^^ and the async* syntax allows us to return the stream type
    const user = User(
      id: '',
      email: '',
      appMetadata: {},
      userMetadata: {},
      aud: '',
      createdAt: "",
      updatedAt: "",
    );
    const session = Session(
      accessToken: '',
      refreshToken: '',
      expiresIn: 0,
      tokenType: '',
      user: user,
    );

    yield AuthState(AuthChangeEvent.userDeleted, session);
  }

  static Stream<AuthState> authenticated() async* {
    final user = User(
      id: 'id',
      email: 'test@example.com',
      appMetadata: {},
      userMetadata: {},
      aud: 'aud',
      createdAt: DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
      updatedAt: DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
    );
    final session = Session(
      accessToken: 'access_token',
      refreshToken: 'refresh_token',
      expiresIn: 3600,
      tokenType: 'bearer',
      user: user,
    );
    yield AuthState(AuthChangeEvent.signedIn, session);
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [unauthenticated(), authenticated()];
}
// ^^ For Equatable
```

And you can then use it in your test files by importing the fixture and then calling any one of the static methods like this: `SupabaseAuthFixture.authenticated()` and I now have a supabase compliant mock type that I can use in my unit tests, hope this helps!!